# How to check if code is running in Unity on any platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a C# library that can be used in Unity or any generic mono/.NET application. I would like some of the code to behave differently depending on whether it's running in a Unity context or something else.

Looking at [the available #define flags in the Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), it looks like there isn't one single #define that covers all platforms. The listing for UNITY_STANDALONE reads

> #define directive for compiling/executing code for any standalone platform (Mac OS X, Windows or Linux).

Which implies to me that the only way to get full coverage would be

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WII || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_PS4 || UNITY_XBOXONE || UNITY_TIZEN || UNITY_TVOS || UNITY_WSA || UNITY_WEBGL || UNITY_FACEBOOK
```

Is there a better way to detect if the code is running in Unity?

Comment: I'd usually suggest reversing the concept - let the consumer *tell you* what behaviour it wants, rather than trying to divine it.

Comment: I would use UNITY_5_OR_NEWER. *shrug*

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is a good thing to keep in mind for sure

Comment: @RetiredNinja Do you know of any documentation for that #define? I can't find it in the Unity manual

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I should give a more verbose response: It is a good thing to keep in mind, so that I don't force my assumptions onto the user, but there are many dependencies I can't get to outside of the Unity context, and have to hide under an #if so that the library will compile with msbuild or mono as well.

Comment: The documentation you linked to explains the UNITY_X_OR_NEWER defines.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I missed that completely, thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as the solution

Comment: Use reflection to determine if `UnityEngine` is available?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an answer, lets quote the documentation (Thanks to @RetiredNinja comment)

> You can also compile code selectively based on the earliest version of Unity required to compile or execute a given portion of code. Given the same version format as above (X.Y), Unity exposes one global #define in the format UNITY_X_Y_OR_NEWER, that you can use for this purpose.

So we can use `#ifdef UNITY_5_OR_NEWER` or anything else. This is what I'm using for the bits of code that are shared between unity and regular c# code (Especially around null checks as Unity overrides it)